# How to uniformly scale rich text in an NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, appkit

**Context**:

I have a normal Document-based Cocoa Mac OS X application which uses an `NSTextView` for rich text input. The user may edit the font family, point size and colors of the text in the `NSTextView`.

Base SDK: 10.7
Deployment Target: 10.6

---

**Question:**

I would like to implement zooming of the entire UI programmatically (including the `NSTextView`) while the user is editing text. Scaling the frame of the `NSTextView` is no problem. But I don't know how to scale the editable text inside the view which may contain multiple different point sizes in different sub-sections of the entire run of text.

How can I apply a uniform scale factor to the rich text displayed in an `NSTextView`?

This should play nicely with "rich text", such that the user's font family, color **and especially point size** (which may be different at different points of the run of text) are preserved, but scaled uniformly/relatively.

Is this possible given my Base SDK and Deployment targets? Is it possible with a newer Base SDK or Deployment target?

Comment: Is it possible you could require 10.8 and up and make use of 10.8's built-in text zooming? If you can require 10.8 and the text doesn't have to wrap to the zoomed area, this might be a way forward. See TextEdit's View > Zoom... menu items.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the intent is to scale the view (and not actually change the attributes in the string), I would suggest using scaleUnitSquareToSize: method: along with the ScalingScrollView (available with the TextEdit sample code) for the proper scroll bar behavior.

The core piece from the ScalingScrollView is:

```
- (void)setScaleFactor:(CGFloat)newScaleFactor adjustPopup:(BOOL)flag
{
CGFloat oldScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
    if (scaleFactor != newScaleFactor)
    {
        NSSize curDocFrameSize, newDocBoundsSize;
        NSView *clipView = [[self documentView] superview];

        scaleFactor = newScaleFactor;

        // Get the frame.  The frame must stay the same.
        curDocFrameSize = [clipView frame].size;

        // The new bounds will be frame divided by scale factor
        newDocBoundsSize.width = curDocFrameSize.width / scaleFactor;
        newDocBoundsSize.height = curDocFrameSize.height / scaleFactor;
    }
    scaleFactor = newScaleFactor;
    [scale_delegate scaleChanged:oldScaleFactor newScale:newScaleFactor]; 
}
```

The `scale_delegate` is your delegate that can adjust your `NSTextView` object:

```
- (void) scaleChanged:(CGFloat)oldScale newScale:(CGFloat)newScale
{
    NSInteger     percent  = lroundf(newScale * 100);

    CGFloat scaler = newScale / oldScale;   
    [textView scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(scaler, scaler)];

    NSLayoutManager* lm = [textView layoutManager];
    NSTextContainer* tc = [textView textContainer];
    [lm ensureLayoutForTextContainer:tc];
}
```

The `scaleUnitSquareToSize:` method scales relative to its current state, so you keep track of your scale factor and then convert your absolute scale request (200%) into a relative scale request.

Comment: Thanks, lots of good info here! I will dig in and update my response when done.

Comment: Update: This was exactly the info I needed. I was able to use the `-scaleUnitSquareToSize:` method to achieve what I wanted. Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 7):

Works for both iOS and Mac OS

```
@implementation NSAttributedString (Scale)

- (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringWithScale:(double)scale
{
    if(scale == 1.0)
    {
        return self;
    }

    NSMutableAttributedString *copy = [self mutableCopy];
    [copy beginEditing];

    NSRange fullRange = NSMakeRange(0, copy.length);

    [self enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:fullRange options:0 usingBlock:^(UIFont *oldFont, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        double currentFontSize = oldFont.pointSize;
        double newFontSize = currentFontSize * scale;

        // don't trust -[UIFont fontWithSize:]
        UIFont *scaledFont = [UIFont fontWithName:oldFont.fontName size:newFontSize];

        [copy removeAttribute:NSFontAttributeName range:range];
        [copy addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:scaledFont range:range];
    }];

    [self enumerateAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName inRange:fullRange options:0 usingBlock:^(NSParagraphStyle *oldParagraphStyle, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *newParagraphStyle = [oldParagraphStyle mutableCopy];
        newParagraphStyle.lineSpacing *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacing *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.headIndent *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.tailIndent *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.minimumLineHeight *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.maximumLineHeight *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacing *= scale;
        newParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore *= scale;

        [copy removeAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName range:range];
        [copy addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:newParagraphStyle range:range];
    }];

    [copy endEditing];
    return copy;
}

@end
```

Comment: This is the ideal answer for me, as it seems more universal. Works with NSTextField and NSTextView. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

OP here.

I found one solution that kinda works and is not terribly difficult to implement. I'm not sure this is the best/ideal solution however. I'm still interested in finding other solutions. But here's one way:

Manually scale the *font point size* and *line height multiple* properties of the `NSAttributedString` source text before display, and then un-scale the displayed text before storing as source.

The problem with this solution is that while scaled, the system **Font Panel** will show the actual scaled display point size of selected text (rather than the "real" source point size) while editing. That's not desirable.

---

Here's my implementation of that:

```
- (void)scaleAttributedString:(NSMutableAttributedString *)str by:(CGFloat)scale {
    if (1.0 == scale) return;

    NSRange r = NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);
    [str enumerateAttribute:NSFontAttributeName inRange:r options:0 usingBlock:^(NSFont *oldFont, NSRange range, BOOL *stop) {
        NSFont *newFont = [NSFont fontWithName:[oldFont familyName] size:[oldFont pointSize] * scale];

        NSParagraphStyle *oldParaStyle = [str attribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName atIndex:range.location effectiveRange:NULL];
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *newParaStyle = [[oldParaStyle mutableCopy] autorelease];

        CGFloat oldLineHeight = [oldParaStyle lineHeightMultiple];
        CGFloat newLineHeight = scale * oldLineHeight;
        [newParaStyle setLineHeightMultiple:newLineHeight];

        id newAttrs = @{
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: newParaStyle,
            NSFontAttributeName: newFont,
        };
        [str addAttributes:newAttrs range:range];
    }];    
}
```

This requires scaling the source text before display:

```
// scale text
CGFloat scale = getCurrentScaleFactor();
[self scaleAttributedString:str by:scale];
```

And then reverse-scaling the displayed text before storing as source:

```
// un-scale text
CGFloat scale = 1.0 / getCurrentScaleFactor();
[self scaleAttributedString:str by:scale];
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank Mark Munz for his answer, as it saved me from wandering in a dark forest, full of of NSScrollView magnification madness and NSLayoutManagers.

For anyone still looking, this is my approach. This code is inside a NSDocument. All text is being inset into a fixed-width and centered container, and the zooming here keeps word wrapping etc. intact. It creates a nice "page view" sort of appearance without resorting to complicated layout management.

You need to have `CGFloat _documentSize` and `NSTextView textView` constants set in you class for this example to work.

```c
- (void) initZoom {
    // Call this when the view has loaded and is ready
    // I am storing a separate _scaleFactor and _magnification for my own purposes, mainly to have the initial scale to be higher than 1.0
    _scaleFactor = 1.0;
    _magnification = 1.1;
    [self setScaleFactor:_magnification adjustPopup:false];

    [self updateLayout];
    // NOTE: You might need to call updateLayout after the content is set and we know the window size etc.
}

- (void) zoom: (bool) zoomIn {
    if (!_scaleFactor) _scaleFactor = _magnification;

    // Arbitrary maximum levels of zoom
    if (zoomIn) {
        if (_magnification < 1.6) _magnification += 0.1;
    } else {
        if (_magnification > 0.8) _magnification -= 0.1;
    }

    [self setScaleFactor:_magnification adjustPopup:false];
    [self updateLayout];
}

- (void)setScaleFactor:(CGFloat)newScaleFactor adjustPopup:(BOOL)flag
{
    CGFloat oldScaleFactor = _scaleFactor;
    if (_scaleFactor != newScaleFactor)
    {
        NSSize curDocFrameSize, newDocBoundsSize;
        NSView *clipView = [[self textView] superview];

        _scaleFactor = newScaleFactor;

        // Get the frame.  The frame must stay the same.
        curDocFrameSize = [clipView frame].size;

        // The new bounds will be frame divided by scale factor
        //newDocBoundsSize.width = curDocFrameSize.width / _scaleFactor;
        newDocBoundsSize.width = curDocFrameSize.width;
        newDocBoundsSize.height = curDocFrameSize.height / _scaleFactor;

        NSRect newFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, newDocBoundsSize.width, newDocBoundsSize.height);
        clipView.frame = newFrame;
    }
    _scaleFactor = newScaleFactor;
    [self scaleChanged:oldScaleFactor newScale:newScaleFactor];
}
- (void) scaleChanged:(CGFloat)oldScale newScale:(CGFloat)newScale
{
    CGFloat scaler = newScale / oldScale;
    [self.textView scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(scaler, scaler)];

    NSLayoutManager* lm = [self.textView layoutManager];
    NSTextContainer* tc = [self.textView textContainer];
    [lm ensureLayoutForTextContainer:tc];
}

- (void) updateLayout {
    CGFloat width = (self.textView.frame.size.width / 2 - _documentWidth * _magnification / 2) / _magnification;    self.textView.textContainerInset = NSMakeSize(width, TEXT_INSET_TOP);
    self.textView.textContainer.size = NSMakeSize(_documentWidth, self.textView.textContainer.size.height);
}
```